# Get records from a table with timestamps / echo a message in the row when the timestamp difference is more than 5 minutes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I get a list of records and each record is a question / answer / timestamp.

I created a basic PHP report:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "login", "pass");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("db", $con);

$result = mysql_query(" SELECT *
                FROM  `experiment` 
                where userid = 73");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "question " . $row['question'] . "answer " . $row['answer'] .
         "time " . $row['time'] . "stamp " . $row['createdAt'] . "<br>";
}
```

I need some way to compare the row in front of createdAt and the row after createdAt.

If the difference between two rows is bigger then 2 minutes, the thing should echo "warning".

Comment: Can you clearly explain what you require ??

Comment: You should read the FAQ on how to ask a good question. Took me a while to figure out what you likely meant...

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume a couple of things on your behalf. This may change the value of the answer, but you simply haven't provided the necessary information for an answer to be feasible at this point.

I am going to assume that you are *looping* through the data records. You imply this by stating that there is a display of multiple rows. Your SQL query only gets the data of one row. I'll assume that you actually have gotten an entire record set instead. Because otherwise, the data structure needs to be examined for its design choices. I am also making an assumption on how `userid` is used in a table, mind, so that's my personal bias.

As record sets are collected, they can be manipulated. You're using the ancient `mysql_*` method here. I recommend that you read the PDO methodology that php has available at 5.2.7+ and consider upgrading your php version if you don't already have it.

The manipulation can take many forms.

```
$previousRecord = 0;
foreach ($recordSet as $index=>$record){
    $recordSet[$index]['warningTime'] = FALSE;
    if ($previousRecord){
        if (($record['createdAt']-$previousRecord) > 120){
            $recordSet[$index]['warningTime'] = TRUE;
        }
    }
    $previousRecord = $record['createdAt'];
    // Other data manipulation logic for page presentation
}
```

This should inject the warning right into the dataset that can be displayed whenever you want it to be. I do prefer a seperation of functions for maintainability; calling the database, extracting/formatting the data, displaying the data. It makes future changes *much* easier, also allows for code portability. You do not have this in your code, which means that whenever you do something like this again, well, you'll re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

```
$createdAt = null;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) :
    // initialise on first run
    if ($createdAt === null) :
        $createdAt = $row['createdAt'];
    endif;
    // now $createdAt is the value of the last row... if so, echo warning, else echo nothing
    echo checkCreatedIsOlderThanTwoMinutes($createdAt, $row['createdAt']) === true ? "WARNING!" : "";
    echo "question ". $row['question']. "answer ". $row['answer']. "time ".$row['time']."stamp ". $row['createdAt']."<br>";

endwhile;
```

I don't have a clue what the format of your createdAt looks like, so I use this pseudo-function:

```
function checkCreatedIsOlderThanTwoMinutes($oldCreatedAt, $newCreatedAd)
{
     // check that stuff
}
```

Hope that helps.